# Can I send email in the background in Mutt while still being notified of errors?

Tags: mutt, sendmail, smtp

## Removing mutt's send delay

I originally used mutt's built-in SMTP MTA. However, there is a considerable pause after hitting send. This can be disabled by using an external MTA with `set sendmail_wait=-1` in `muttrc`.

However, if I use `msmtp` as the MTA, then there is no notification of errors (although `msmtp` does write to `logfile` as specified in `~/.msmtprc`).

## Attempt to get notifications

From the command line, I can trigger a command when `msmtp` fails.

```
</tmp/tosend msmtp -a default foo@bar.com --read-envelope-from || echo failed
```

Conceivably, I could mail a failure notification to my local *nix mail. However, this doesn't seem to work in mutt, if I set the following in `muttrc`.

```
set sendmail = "/usr/bin/msmtp || date >> /tmp/msmtp.fail"
```

This causes all email to fail to send silently, with the following error in `msmtp`'s `logfile`.

```
Nov 05 10:53:09 host=mail.bar.com tls=on auth=on user=foo@bar.com from=foo@bar.com recipients=||,date,>>,/tmp/msmtp.fail,foo@bar.com smtpstatus=501 smtpmsg='501 #5.1.1 bad address ' errormsg='recipient address >> not accepted by the server' exitcode=EX_DATAERR
```

Obviously, `mutt` is parsing the extra parts of the command as recipients.

## Question

Is there a way to get notifications of sent emails that fail, while sending in the background? I'm not tied to `msmtp` necessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write yourself a tiny shell script to use as a "sendmail" value. Eg configure
`~/.muttrc` with

```
set sendmail = /home/yourid/bin/mymuttsendmail
```

and in `mymuttsendmail` put something like

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/mymutt.XXXXXX)
cat >$tmp
( if ! msg=$(msmtp "$@" <$tmp 2>&1)
  then zenity --error --text "$msg"
  fi 
  rm $tmp
) &
exit 0
```

and `chmod +x` this file. 
Remember this script will be called with the recipients as extra args,
which we pass to msmtp with `"$@"`, and the mail will be on stdin, which
we copy immediately into a temporary file to then give to `msmtp`. Any error messages are captured in variable `msg` and if the
return code is a failure you can run a popup dialog like zenity, for example.

Comment: Interesting solution! (+1) However, I feel like `exim` may be more robust, so I'll [persist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240885/can-i-send-email-in-the-background-in-mutt-while-still-being-notified-of-errors/241632#comment413934_240906) with working that out. I'll revisit your answer if I give up with `exim`.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work. The sent mail is severely garbled. It seems to strip off most headers, and the body is absent. I retried with vanilla `msmtp` as `$sendmail`, and that worked fine.

Comment: I think I know what might be happening. I've edited the script to capture the mail first into a temporary file, then run msmtp in the background.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly now. (I suppose that was related to the "open attachment in external program" issue, where the file was deleted/truncated before fully opening?)

Comment: Yes, I was being a bit naive in assuming the file behind stdin would be left intact by mutt when, as it sees it, the sending process has ended.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a better nullmailer, `msmtp` is about as minimalist as it gets?  or even a full MTA like exim or postfix (they're not very difficult to configure)?

There's a list of other nullmailer options at http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Mail/nullmailers.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm more than happy to use a different MTA (as per the question), and I've got exim installed anyway. However, do you know which (if any) would provide some kind of feedback or trigger a script on errors?

Comment: a real MTA will bounce the message back to the sender if there was any error.  btw, why even bother with `msmtp` if you have `exim` installed?

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing `exim`now… which is ridiculously confusing to set up (at least in Arch). I used `msmtp` because I followed the first few suggestions that I found for mutt. Also, after more investigation, `exim` requires the password stored in plaintext, and must be configured system-wide, instead of `msmtp`'s user-level configuration.

Comment: And I just can't work exim out… New question asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241456/how-can-i-set-up-exim-to-use-my-isps-smtp-server-on-a-non-debian-system).

Answer (score 1):

meuh's answer was very helpful. Here's a simpler version of mymuttsendmail.
Replace `username` with your username in the following code so it can
email you locally in case there's an error.  The variable $? stores
the exit code of msmtp, and uses local mail to email you if there's an
error sending your email.  Just remember to set sendmail_wait=-1.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/msmtp "$@" 2>&1
VAL=$?
if (($VAL))
then 
    # message not sent
    echo "Error sending mail to $@, exit code $VAL" | mail -s 'ERROR' username
fi
```